# Will Freezing My Credit Score Help Me Hide My Current Address?

Tags: credit, credit-report, credit-history

I grew up in an abusive household and don't speak to my parents.

Recently they found out where I live - very far away from them - and showed up unannounced at my door.

I understand my credit report has my address on it and I believe that is how they found me.

If I freeze my credit score with all 3 bureaus, will that stop anyone other than myself from pulling it, and therefore having access to my address?

Are there any other options that would help me hide my address?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a note - I have found the names and addresses of people I knew in college many years ago (and had not kept up with since) using nothing by free sites on the internet and a bit of knowledge of them and deduction.

Answer (score 3):

Your parents should not have been able to view your credit report without your permission, whether or not it is frozen. If they did, they probably did it by posing as you (which is fraud). Since freezing your credit does not prevent *you* from viewing your own credit report, it would also not prevent anyone posing as you from viewing it.

If your parents viewed your credit report by posing as someone who you have applied to for credit, then a credit freeze could prevent that.

Comment: Once a credit freeze was in place, the parents would need the credit freeze pin to access the credit report.  That would prevent that method of finding you, but there are many other ways to locate you, so I don’t think this will really help you...

Comment: @BrianBorchers A little off topic, but what are some other common ways for someone to track you down? I want to protect myself as best as possible.

Comment: It’s generally easy to trace someone through their network of friends or simply by name, profession, etc.  if you want to not be found by your family you’ll need to change your name and cutoff ties with your old friends.

Comment: Probably easier to get a restraining order than to keep your location a secret.

Comment: What did you do when they showed up at your door?  Did you make it perfectly clear?  Something like: "I told you that I never wanted to see you again. Leave now or I will call the police". Next step, restraining order like Hart said.